# ASP within ASP with HTML

Tags: asp-classic, safari

I have an ASP array, e.g., bytCompareArray(36,2). The first column can have any integer between 1 and 9 in it. The second only 1 or 2. I have a second variable, e.g., bytID_Compare, that can hold any integer from 1 to 36 - but generally starts at 1 and moves up to 36. I which to use use this these together to compare two images, the images being named, color1.pgn,  color2.pgn,  color3.pgn, etc. Therefore:

```
   <img src="Color1.png">      - works

   <img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(1,1))%>.png">         - works
```

but

```
  <img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png">         - fails

  <img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(<%=bytID_Compare%>,1))%>.png">    - fails

  <img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray%>(<%=bytID_Compare%>,1)).png">    - fails
```

Any suggestions. The idea being to use the array to make all 36 comparisons of each of the 9 images to each other (8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 36). Thanks. Rick

It fails in that it gives me a broken image icon. If I click on that icon and ask it to "open image in new window (or tab)" it does so - which I did not realize until now. And now we get a little further. I have been testing in Safari - it fails in Safari. It works in Chrome and Firefox. So now the question is only why does it fail in Safari? And, then, is there a way to get it to work in Safari?

Comment: Why does <%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png"> fail? What's the message? is bytID_Compare assigned to a value?

Comment: It fails in that it gives me a ? - no message. If I click on that ? and ask it to "open image in new window (or tab)" it does so - which I did not realize until now. And now we get a little further. I have been testing in Safari - it fails in Safari - if works in Crome and Firefox. So now the question is only why does it fail in Safari? And, then, is there a way to get it to work in Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Try
    `<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(cint(bytID_Compare),1))%>.png">`
The array subscript is expecting integer variables and if bytID_Compare is in any other format, it will not accept. Apart from that the first example looks good.

The second example is not working because of nested ASP tags.

The third example is not working because trim(bytCompareArray in itself is not validated by ASP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(1,1))%>.png">
```

is the equivalent of

```
<img src="Color<% Response.Write (trim(bytCompareArray(1,1))) %>.png">
```

The lines

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(<%=bytID_Compare%>,1))%>.png">
```

and

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray%>(<%=bytID_Compare%>,1)).png">
```

have nested <%= %> tags

you should rewrite these lines to follow the format of the working line as follows

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that opening the image in a new tab works fine, this sounds like cache issue.

Try appending some changing value to the image URL:

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png?t=<%=CLng(Timer())%>" />
```

This will append value that will change every second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
<img src="Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png">
```

should work.

Check bytID_Compare have the correct value in the range 1 to 36. View the source to find if the src have correct link. Also try adding the full path excluding the domain name like

```
<img src="/Images/Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png">.
```

If the image is in root folder try the following

```
<img src="/Color<%=trim(bytCompareArray(bytID_Compare,1))%>.png">
```

Hope this helps...